# How can I make text left justified?

Tags: html

i tried using `<input type="text" id="nam_beneficiary" size="70" style   ="BORDER-STYLE: none;align:left" value=""/>` but it didnt work, pls how can I make it justify from the left, so thyat while printing it will align from the left instead of the right

Comment: can we have more information about what you are talking about ?

Comment: Your question is not clear . Can you explain more : please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: `text-align: left`, perhaps? `align` will apply to the input itself, not its contents.

Comment: @MarcB: No; `align` doesn't exist.

Comment: I thought it existed but was deprecated.

Comment: @SLaks isnt text aligned to the left by default ?

Comment: text-align:justify should be enough

Comment: use 'text-align:left;', not 'align:left';

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

try it our self

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.container
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}
.right
{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
width:300px;
background-color:#b0e0e6;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="right">
<p><b>Note: </b><input type="text" id="nam_beneficiary" size="70" style ="BORDER-STYLE: none;align:left" value=""/> </p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```